# Manually start HDFS every time I boot?

Tags: bash, hadoop, hdfs, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

Laconically: **Should I start HDFS *every* that I come back to the cluster after a power-off operation?**

---

I have successfully created a Hadoop cluster (after [loosing some battles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725444/help-me-win-this-war)) and now I want to be very careful on proceeding with this.

Should I execute `start-dfs.sh` every time I power on the cluster, or it's ready to execute my application's code? Same for `start-yarn.sh`.

I am afraid that if I run it without everything being fine, it might leave garbage directories after execution.

Comment: So you installed hadoop locally in Ubuntu? Then the tags for distributed /cluster computing are a bit much

Comment: The virtualbox plays the role of the other node @cricket_007.

Comment: So 2 nodes? Local and VirtualBox? The default replication factor for hdfs is 3 nodes

Comment: Not my decision @cricket_007, nothing I can do about it. I do not think that the number of nodes is the points of my question though.

Comment: I believe you're question wanted "everything being fine". Meaning you need to meet the minimum requirements for starting hdfs (or yarn). If you don't, it might work, but it'll certainly give warnings

Comment: No @cricket_007 it works. Let me update the question please.

Comment: I don't really understand what/when the alternative to starting hdfs would be. You need it, zookeeper, and yarn all running to run at least a mapreduce job

Comment: I am not asking for an alternative @cricket_007. I did execute them first time I created the cluster. I run an example, I power-off the cluster. Next day I power on the cluster. Should I start HDFS/yarn, or I am ready to run an example right away?

Comment: The services should at least be stopped before power cycling. I wouldn't recommend just turning off the cluster machines

Comment: OK @cricket_007, I would accept that as an answer, so go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from playing around with the Hortonworks and Cloudera sandboxes, I can say turning them on and off doesn't seem to demonstrate any "side-effects".

However, it is necessary to start the needed services everytime the cluster starts.

As far as power cycling goes in a real cluster, it is recommended to stop the services running on the respective nodes before powering them down (`stop-dfs.sh` and `stop-yarn.sh`). That way there are no weird problems and any errors on the way to stopping the services will be properly logged on each node.

Comment: How to power them down? It would be nice to have that in your answer. :)

Comment: Hmm. I use Ambari on a Hortonworks installation or Cloudera Manager for Cloudera.... Is there no stop equivalent script for the start ones?